# Conversion of java.util.Date to java.sql.Date truncates the time part

Tags: java, sql-server, date

I am trying to save a `java.util.Date` from an application to my SQL Server database using JDBC.

When I convert the `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date` using the method below, it truncates the time part.

```
java.sql.Date javaSqlExpiryDate = new java.sql.Date(javaUtilExpiryDate.getTime());
System.out.println("javaUtilExpiryDate: " + javaUtilExpiryDate.toString());
System.out.println("javaSqlExpiryDate: " + javaSqlExpiryDate.toString());
```

The **Console** window reports the output as:

> javaUtilExpiryDate: Thu Sep 01 18:19:08 IST 2016
>
> javaSqlExpiryDate: 2016-09-01

How do I get it to retain the time part as well?

Comment: Do you really need to convert it, if loosing the time part is not what you want? Why not use the java.util.Date directly in your jdbc call?

Comment: @stenix I checked the overloads of the `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method and none of them seem to want a `java.util.Date`. They all work with `java.sql.*` types.

Comment: FYI, you are using the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. In JDBC 4.2 and later you may be able to pass/fetch java.time objects directly via `setObject` and `getObject` methods without going through java.sql types. If not, look for new conversion methods added to the old classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's the expected and documented behavior.

[Quote from the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

If you want to keep the time, you need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` (especially if the column in the database is defined as `datetime`).

Comment: Thank you. I am using the JDBC `PreparedStatement` to parameterize the SQL. That guy needs a `java.sql.Date`, so I how do I get from a `java.sql.Timestamp` to a `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 You can't. You **have** to use `java.sql.Timestamp` and `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just saw that. 6 more minutes before I can mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your import from `java.sql.Date` TO `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: I think you did it the other way around. I need a `java.sql.Date` *from* a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Sorry i got your question wrong. Refer updated answer

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedObject.setObject(
    1 ,
    myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()  // Convert legacy object to modern java.time object, `Instant`.
)
```

## Details

The other Answers are correct. The `java.util.Date` class represents a date *and* a time-of-day in UTC. The `java.sql.Date` represents only a date, without the time-of-day. Well, actually, the `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to represent only a date but actually, as a badly-designed hack, subclasses the `java.util.Date` class and therefore does have a time-of-day. Confusing? Yes. One of many reasons to avoid these awful old legacy classes.

Now we have a better way, the java.time classes.

## java.time

In the old days you would convert your `java.util.Date` object to a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Now, with a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) supporting JDBC 4.2 and later, you can send your java.time objects directly to/from the database. No need for either the java.util nor java.sql classes, just stick with java.time classes.

If you have to interface with old code using `java.util.Date`, convert to `java.time.Instant` using new methods added to the old classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Exchange an `Instant` with the database via `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

To see this moment through some other time zone than UTC, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).